# Wi-fi connection failing on Arch Linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

I' ve just installed Arch Linux on my computer, I have some problems:
If I write

```
# iwconfig
```

The result is

```
-bash: iwconfig: command not found
```

the same is with `ifconfig`
instead if I try with

```
# wifi-menu
```

I have

```
Please install 'dialog' to use wifi-menu
```

I don't have a modem to connect wire. What should I do?

Comment: I' ve solved using a ethernet wire and writing

    dhcpcd
than I tried to ping

    ping -c 3 www.google.it
And I saw that now I'm connected ;)

Comment: Now I' m again disconnetted and I don' t know why, iwconfig still doesn't work

Comment: After dialog install the connection is fallen downl EDIT: MY ETH WIRE IS BROKEN -.-" but iwconfig??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iwconfig` is part of the `wireless_tools` package, and `ifconfig` is part of `net-tools` on my Arch laptop (relatively up-to-date). To install:

```
pacman -S wireless_tools  net-tools
```

It sounds like you need to educate yourself on the use of `systemctl` to start/stop the DHCP client service.  My first guess after "bad cable" would be that `dhcpcd` isn't working correctly.